# jcabi is not logging in a file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jcabi

I am trying to log using jcabi-log as described in link at http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/23/avoid-java-static-logger.html.

I have a method `runThisAdvise()` which is getting called from main method. The text in `Logger.info` "I am here" is not printing in the `log1.out` file. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

```
import com.jcabi.log.Logger;

public class StaticLogger {
    private int c;
    private int a=5;
    private int b=2;

    public int runThisAdvise() {
        c=a+b;
        Logger.info(this,"I am here");
        System.out.println("blah" +c);
        return c;
     }
}
```

log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE,CONSOLE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=D:\\log1.out
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern= %r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who has similar issue check your log4j configuration and properties file. Here are the steps to make sure you have your jcabi-log4j-slf4j configured correctly.

1) Add following dependencies to maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcabi-log</artifactId>
    <version>0.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

2) Make sure log4j.properties file is at correct location i.e src/main/resources

3) After above two steps, the following code should work:

```
package test.jcabi.jcabiProject;

import com.jcabi.log.Logger;

public class JcabiLogger {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Logger.info(jcabiLogger.class,"This is jcabi test");
    }
}
```